# Which artists drew which pictures for the spoofed comic book covers in the title sequence?

Tags: credits, mallrats

In the 1995 [Kevin Smith](https://m.imdb.com/name/nm0003620/?ref_=tt_ov_dr) film [Mallrats](https://m.imdb.com/title/tt0113749/?ref_=m_ttfcd_tt), who are all the featured artists that drew spoofed comic book covers for the film's title sequence and which covers did they draw?

After randomly rewatching the film (27 years later), I was still plagued by this question, so to supplement my pre-existing knowledge and my educated guesses, I searched online and found a [descriptive list](https://everything2.com/title/Mallrats) of all the covers depicted in the intro, as well as this [gallery](https://viewaskew.com/mallrats/comictoast.html) depicting low resolution images of the covers themselves. However, surprisingly, no compendium of the artists themselves corresponding to which covers they drew actually exists.

So, **who are they?** and **which covers did they draw?**

Answer (score 12):

This is the master list with the title, the artist(s), and (to save space) only the links corresponding to individual cover images should you want to view them yourself.

[Angry Pop Comix](https://viewaskew.com/mallrats/images/comic/angrypop.jpg), artist: [Ethan Van Sciver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ethan_Van_Sciver)

[Defective Comics](https://viewaskew.com/mallrats/images/comic/defective.jpg), artist: [Mike Allred](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mike_Allred)

[Legends of the Dork Knights](http://www.viewaskew.com/images/mallrats/dork.jpg), Pencils: [Joe Quesada](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joe_Quesada) inks: [Jimmy Palmiotti](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jimmy_Palmiotti)

[Adventures of The Man](https://viewaskew.com/mallrats/images/comic/stan.jpg), artist: [Chuck Frazier](https://leagueofcomicgeeks.com/people/16414/chuck-frazier) (as "[Chuck Frasier](https://m.imdb.com/name/nm1219393/?ref_=m_ttfcd_cr10)" IMDB)

[New Jersey Malls 07732](https://viewaskew.com/mallrats/images/comic/brenda.jpg), artist: [Jae Lee](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jae_Lee)

[Buttman Adventures](https://viewaskew.com/mallrats/images/comic/buttman.jpg), artist: [Kirk Van Wormer](https://www.imdb.com/name/nm0888320/)

[Brandi - The last babe on earth](https://viewaskew.com/mallrats/images/comic/brandi.jpg), artist: [Jason Pearson](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jason_Pearson)

[The Incredible Bulk](https://viewaskew.com/mallrats/images/comic/bulk.jpg), artist: [Dave Johnson](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dave_Johnson_(comics))

[Weapon Sex](https://viewaskew.com/mallrats/images/comic/weaponsex.jpg), artist: [Brian Stelfreeze](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brian_Stelfreeze)

[Fantastic Two](https://viewaskew.com/mallrats/images/comic/fantastictwo.jpg), artist: [Cully Hamner](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cully_Hamner)

[Gwen 13](https://viewaskew.com/mallrats/images/comic/gwen13.jpg), artist: [Adam Hughes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adam_Hughes)

[Brodieman](https://viewaskew.com/mallrats/images/comic/brodieman.jpg), pencils: [J. Scott Campbell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/J._Scott_Campbell), inks: [Alex Gardner](https://dc.fandom.com/wiki/Category:Alex_Gardner/Cover_Artist_Images) (as "[Alex Garner](https://m.imdb.com/name/nm1219401/?ref_=m_ttfcd_cr11)" IMDB)

[Mallrats](https://viewaskew.com/mallrats/images/comic/mallratsc.jpg), artist(s): [Brandon Peterson](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brandon_Peterson)? No Sig. Cell painting?

My [self-help](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/self-help) effort started with the [IMDB page for the Mallrats film art department](https://m.imdb.com/title/tt0113749/fullcredits/art_department), at this point I knew I would be digging in the crates for an answer. I made a list of artists tagged with the credit "main title" and began with those whose drawing styles were known or obvious. Next I started zooming in on the covers to find signatures from the [page](https://viewaskew.com/mallrats/comictoast.html) with the low-resolution cover scans. The signatures I recognized or obviously correlated to the list, I made a note of, and any which were not known to me or too stylized to be legible I began [googling](https://www.google.com/) artists on the list with "signature" as the additional search criteria. My goal was to answer my own question and create a 2 click compendium for those without the motivation to look further than 2 clicks from their initial search results.

If you have real confirmation that someone did inks on something, or who colored what, feel free to edit with updates but for ease of reading please try to follow the existing format.

Additional main title artists listed on IMDB, credited but unaccounted for: [Joe Benitez](https://m.imdb.com/name/nm1219341/?ref_=m_ttfcd_cr4), [David Finch](https://m.imdb.com/name/nm3259973/?ref_=m_ttfcd_cr8), [Frank Gomez](https://m.imdb.com/name/nm1215529/?ref_=m_ttfcd_cr12), [Jason Martin](https://m.imdb.com/name/nm1215559/?ref_=m_ttfcd_cr27),
[Karl Story](https://m.imdb.com/name/nm1218020/?ref_=m_ttfcd_cr37), [Anthony Winn (as Anthony Win)](https://m.imdb.com/name/nm2342445/?ref_=m_ttfcd_cr42)